# How to focus the cursor to the starting position of a textbox with pre inserted slashes (_ _/_ _/_ _ _ _) for a date field in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver

I have a textbox which has slashes already inserted like (_ */* */* _ _ _) . The problem I am running into is the cursor is being placed at the end of the textbox and not taking the date since the date is entered from the starting position of the textbox. The value I am passing is in this format ("mmddyyyy").

```
Dim BirthDate As String
BirthDate = Format(Range(cell).Value, "mmddyyyy")

bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='DateOfBirth']").SendKeys BirthDate 
' when I run this line the cursor goes to the last position in the textbox.
```

How do I set the focus of the cursor to the starting position. The script I have written is in VBA automation with selenium webdriver, chromedriver.

Comment: Did you try to `.Clear` the textbox first? You might need to use `BirthDate = Format(Range(cell).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")` then. • Alternatively try to send a `.SendKeys(Keys.Home)` first (before you start sending the date).

Comment: Could you not just send the [END] key once you have clicked on the field?

Comment: @Zac he tries to automate send keys into textbox in a html form in chrome. So probably without user interaction ;) And you probably meant the HOME key?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: Well spotted.. I had missed `chromedriver` bit :)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I tried clearing those slashes in the textbox they did not do anything, since I cannot clear them I cannot send the date in "mm/dd/yyyy". I tried .click the textbox which inserted the cursor somewhere in the middle of the textbox which enters only some part of the string. I just tried sending this .SendKeys(Keys.Home) before the date which gave me the error object required.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Can you tell me which reference should I add to make the Keys object working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have declared something like

```
Dim bot As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
```

So declare there as well

```
Dim Keys As New Selenium.Keys
```

and you can use something like

```
Dim BirthDate As String
BirthDate = Format(Range(cell).Value, "mmddyyyy")

bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='DateOfBirth']").SendKeys Keys.Home
bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='DateOfBirth']").SendKeys BirthDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim BirthDate As String
BirthDate = Format(Range(cell).Value, "mmddyyyy")

bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='DateOfBirth']").SendKeys(Keys.Home)
bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='DateOfBirth']").SendKeys(BirthDate)
```

Comment: I tried sending Home KEY but nothing seems to change. VBA is not recognizing Keys object and throwing me object required error even though I declared the keys object before using the properties.

Comment: Try bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='DateOfBirth']").SendKeys {Home}

Comment: I have tried all the ways to send a HOME key but none seem to work. Not only HOME, tried sending other keys like Backspace, Del but sendkeys is not working while sending them.

Comment: @DexterousSikh Note that you have a syntax error in your code. VBA syntax does not allow parentheses `()` on procedures/functions that do not return a value. Therefore `a = …SendKeys(Keys.Home)` or `…SendKeys Keys.Home` is valid syntax while `…SendKeys(Keys.Home)` and `a = …SendKeys Keys.Home` are not. Therefore your code must throw an exception, you must remove the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying PEH.. I was just trying to mention the the steps